# How to render sitemap.xml in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, sitemap

I have added /views/sitemap/index.xml and want it displayed when i go to the relevant url.

```
class SitemapController < ApplicationController

  def index
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.xml
    end
  end

end
```

And in routes.rb

```
  match "sitemap/" => "sitemap#index"
```

Using Rails 3

When I go to mydomain.com/sitemap/ I just get a white page. Any ideas?

index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset
      xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">

<url>
  <loc>http://www.mydomain.com/</loc>
  <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
</url>
</urlset>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you are using your index action to render xml and it will render "index.xml" 
file not "sitemap.xml" which is what you have created in your views

While your routes are correct, you are using the wrong filename in views

Try renaming sitemap.xml file to index.xml ( in the views/sitemap folder)

If you define name routes, you need to define :format with it

```
match "/sitemap/sitemap.[:format]", :to => "sitemap#index"
```

it will pickup your format from there. Also you can define a default format in the routes

```
match "sitemap/sitemap.xml", :to => "sitemap#index", :defaults => {:format => :xml}
```

Comment: Oh, my mistake in the post. I did correct that and still no luck.

Comment: can you paste the content of your index.xml file ?

Comment: added it to original question

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong , but I see 2 reasons:

1. index action doesn't actually do anything judging by this code  sample, it just responds back with   no info.
2. you need to render your object  as xml - if you don't rails, doesn't know you want xml - it just treats it as another file extension. It actually lets you do little tricks - like sending json to an xml request ( thou I have no idea why would anyone try to do that). Thou one useful application is that you can make rails send custom rendering of an object to a common format or render regular data in common format for an unusual extension ( we had a client who wanted csv data for a .dat request)

Here is a short  example, from  a sample home controller:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index

    @m = {
    :color => "yellow",
    :total => "20"
  }

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @m}
    end

  end

end
```

this returns this object as xml:

```
<hash>
 <total>20</total>
 <color>yellow</color>
</hash>
```

Comment: terminal still shows this in the output "Processing by SitemapController#index as HTML
", so it's still going into format.html. I put "format.html  { render :xml => @m}"but that doesn't work either

Comment: That's because your browser sends 'Accept' header with text/html. If you try to fetch it with wget -H 'Accept: text/xml', then you should get the xml version. Overall, you might want to omit the html if it's not used, and respond unconditionally with xml.